# ¿Como puedo unificar dos catch?

Tags: java, excepciones

Estamos haciendo pruebas para aprender a usar excepciones.

```
    public class Principal {

public static void main(String[] args) {

     int arrayEnterosE[]={1,2,3,0,7};

    try{

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayEnterosE.length; i++) {
        int resultado=0;
        int numero=5;

        resultado=numero/arrayEnterosE[i];
    }

     }catch (Exception e){
         System.out.println("No se puede dividir entre cero");
     }
    try {
        System.out.println(arrayEnterosE[7]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Esa posicion no existe en el array");
    } 
    finally    {
    System.out.println("fin de programa");
    }
```

he intentado esto:

```
             try{

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayEnterosE.length; i++) {
        int resultado=0;
        int numero=5;

        resultado=numero/arrayEnterosE[i];
    }

     }catch (Exception e){
         System.out.println("No se puede dividir entre cero");
     }

        System.out.println(arrayEnterosE[7]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Esa posicion no existe en el array");
    } 
    finally    {
    System.out.println("fin de programa");
    }
```

y me da este error:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
> at excepciones.Principal.main(Principal.java:5)
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sobre la base que estás trabajando, no se puede hacer. Cuando sales del bloque `try` no puedes volver a "abrirlo", sólo quedan los `catch` y el `finally`.

La mejor opción viable es hacer varios bloques `catch` de un mismo `try`, capturando excepciones más específicas:

```
try {
  ...
  resultado=numero/arrayEnterosE[i];
  ...
  System.out.println(arrayEnterosE[7]);
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ioe) {
  System.out.println("Esa posicion no existe en el array");
} catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
  System.out.println("No se puede dividir entre cero");
}
```

Por supuesto, al lanzarse la primera excepción dentro del bloque se interrumpe la ejecución, por lo que **solo se captura la primera excepción que ocurra** (la segunda nunca llega a ocurrir porque el código que la lanza no se ejecuta).

La alternativa de hacer solo un `catch` de `Exception` y averiguar por `instanceof` su tipo funciona, aunque es mucho menos común y más difícil de leer.

Puntos a tener en cuenta:

- Si una excepción de las que capturas es subclase de la otra, la subclase debe ir antes. Por ejemplo, si quisieras añadir un `} catch (Exception e) {`, debería ir al final de todo. De lo contrario, te dará un error de compilación (porque la excepción será capturada por el bloque más genérico, y el más específico nunca será ejecutable.

  ```
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // Captura todas las Exception
  } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ioobe) {
    // Todas las ioobe ya han sido capturadas por el bloque superior. ERROR
  }
  ```
- A partir de Java 7, puedes hacer lo contrario, juntar dos excepciones en un `catch`

  ```
   } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
     ...
   } catch (Exception e) {
     ...
   }
  ```
- Entiendo que es en un ejercicio, pero las excepciones se tienen que reservar para situaciones excepcionales. Si hay un riesgo de división por cero o acceder a un elemento inexistente, eso se debería comprobar **antes** de hacer la operación.

Answer (score 1):

Debes de enlazarlos en el mismo Try, según tu código sería así:

```
    try{

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayEnterosE.length; i++) {
            int resultado=0;
            int numero=5;

            resultado=numero/arrayEnterosE[i];
        }

    }catch (ArithmeticException e){
        System.out.println("No se puede dividir entre cero");
    }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException a) {
        System.out.println("Esa posicion no existe en el array");
    } finally {
        System.out.println("fin de programa");
    }

    System.out.println(arrayEnterosE[7]);
```

Eso si, fíjate que en cada 'catch' debe de ir una excepción diferente.

Si lo que quieres es hacer un mismo código para 2 excepciones distintas y no tener que escribir 2 catch con el mismo código repetido, hazlo así:

```
    try{

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayEnterosE.length; i++) {
            int resultado=0;
            int numero=5;

            resultado=numero/arrayEnterosE[i];
        }

    }catch (ArithmeticException | IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("ERRORES...");
    } finally {
        System.out.println("fin de programa");
    }

    System.out.println(arrayEnterosE[7]);
```

Comment: Te lo dije anteriormente, no puedes controlar la misma excepción 2 veces. Como te indique tienes que tener 2 excepciones diferentes como en el ultimo código que te adjunto (eso si, no la que te he puesto sino la que realmente necesites

Comment: Perdona, tienes que englobar las 2 excepciones con el símbolo | , prueba ahora.

Answer (score 1):

Así queda con varios catch

```
 try{

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayEnterosE.length; i++)
    {
        int resultado=0;
        int numero=5;
        resultado=numero/arrayEnterosE[i];            
    }

    System.out.println(arrayEnterosE[7]);

 }
 catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
 {

    System.out.println("No se puede dividir entre cero");
 }        
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e2 )
{
    System.out.println("Esa posicion no existe en el array");
}            
finally
{
    System.out.println("fin de programa");
}
```

IllegalArgumentException es la excepción arrojada cuando se intenta dividir por cero, y ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException cuando te sales de rango del array

Comment: Ahi edite la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Una sentencia `try catch` sirve para ejecutar una pieza de código que en algunos casos puede tener errores o no. En caso de tener errores, estos los podemos de alguna manera atrapar antes de que la ejecución del programa termine por no saber que hacer con este error.

El tema de excepciones es un poco largo pues existen varios conceptos por ahí. Existen trees tipos de errores. Los que puedes verificar antes de que ocurran, los que no puedes verificar, y errores.

Los que puedes verificar antes de que ocurran por ejemplo, son como los de la división por cero, o si estas usando archivos por ejemplo, puedes inferir que a lo mejor el programa pueda que no encuentre el archivo.

Los que no puedes verificar son errores como los de que el indice de un array esta fuera del tamaño de este, o que por ejemplo hagas referencia a algo que no existe.

Y los errores son más del tipo de que te acabes la memoria , o que no se pueda cargar la clase principal por alguna razón.

Un `try catch` se forma principalmente de tres partes. el `try` que es parte en donde vas a poner lo que quieres que se ejecute.
El `catch` que es donde se va a poner el codigo de recuperación en caso de que haya un error.
y el `finally` que es el código que se va a ejecutar haya terminado bien o mal el código que pusiste en el `try`.

Por supuesto quese pueden poner varios catch en el código, para a trapar distintos tipos de errores, y dependiendo de este, que entre al catch que le corresponde.

esto se hace de la siguiente manera.

```
try{
     int resultado=0;
     int numero=5;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayEnterosE.length; i++) {

      resultado=numero/arrayEnterosE[i];

    }

}

 }catch (ArithmeticException e){
     System.out.println(e);
 }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
   System.out.println("Esa posicion no existe en el array "+e);
 } finally    {
   System.out.println("LE programa no se pudo terminar con exito :(");
 }
```

Creo que había unos errores en tu código, la verdad no se que es lo que intentas hacer en realidad, pero cualquier cosa dime, y te puedo ayudar :)